# Alternative to 'Table' input in QGIS 3 Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, qgis-modeler, input

In QGIS 2 graphical modeller I had an input parameter 'Table' for spreadsheets, CSV etc. with no geometry. By now, I'm re-creating all my existing QGIS 2 models from scratch (cp. [Using QGIS 2.x processing model in QGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277373/using-qgis-2-x-processing-model-in-qgis-3-0/296327#296327)) and miss this input parameter 'Table' in QGIS 3.

What should I use instead?

Comment: What kind of algorithms do you use? The `Vector Layer` parameter lets you select loaded layers with no geometry (e.g. csv files). You could then couple this with the `Vector Field` to select columns from your table which could then be used for some algorithm such as _Create points layer from table_.

Comment: @Joseph perhaps you remember https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277373/using-qgis-2-x-processing-model-in-qgis-3-0/296327#296327 (formula is still secret...) Table was the input to a custom script, which returned the value of a certain attribute of the only record in my table. It would be no big deal to rewrite this script for vector layer input, but according to some posts here processing scripts in QGIS 3 seem to have lost their straightforwardness somehow compared to QGIS 2 (cp. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/writing-a-python-processing-script-with-qgis-3-0)

Comment: I just saw that there is a well documented processing script template, I'm going to try it this way...

Comment: what about the 'File/Folder' input type? This actually has a filter to specify CSV, so perhaps this is the way to go? (QGIS 3.18 mind you).

Answer (score 1):

Use Vector Layer with geometry type "Geometry not required"

[image]

Comment: Yes it's working, but it's not ideal. It's not showing **only** tables in the dropdown menu. There is still other vector layers.